# How do you put a LIKE comparison in a ms-access WHERE clause with a subquery?

Tags: sql, ms-access

So given some form of query that's like

```
SELECT u.a FROM Users.u WHERE 'blah' LIKE u.b
```

I want 'blah' to be matched with a different table to get something like

```
SELECT u.a FROM Users.u WHERE '*(Select h.c FROM Taco h WHERE h.text = 'blah')*' LIKE u.b
```

Which is trying to say that given 'blah', i want it to resolve to some value h.c (guaranteed to only be one) and that value to be LIKE u.b

Is there any way to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subquery in the where clause shouldn't need quotes like you have.  Try:

```
SELECT u.a
  FROM Users u
 WHERE u.b like (SELECT h.c
                   FROM Taco h
                  WHERE h.text = 'blah')
```

Also a "like" comparision typically means a wildcard search is desired.  This can be done by adding '%' to the end of what's selected in the subquery.  You'll also note that the "search" text goes on the right-hand side of "like":

```
SELECT u.a
  FROM Users u
 WHERE u.b like (SELECT h.c
                   FROM Taco h
                  WHERE h.text = 'blah') || '%'
```